# php mysql create Facebook type users friendship notification in text

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried upto end everything to the best of my knowledge but all in vain. I'm building a community website and i am stuck at one thing. I want to display a text on my wall when my friends become friends with other users. Just like Facebook displays it. For eg.

"John doe is now friends with max stone"

And

"John doe is now friends with max stone and 5 other people"

I am successfully getting it displayed but not like the one I showed above. I do it using while loop from notifications table. I tried but couldn't get it like facebook shows. so please help me get this thing done.

I am posting my code so that you can get clear idea of my code and my mistakes in my code so you can clear.

```
$ check_if_friendship_created = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `users_notifications` 
WHERE `friend_1_username` IN (SELECT `friend_2_username` FROM `users_friends` 
WHERE `friend_1_username` = '". $ logged_user ['username']."') 
GROUP BY `friend_2_fullname` ORDER BY `notification_time` DESC");
```

also to let you all know that my friends table is a symmetrical in design...

looking forward to your positive reponse. Thank you....

Comment: you got column for every friend? or everyone can have only `x` friends? Thats bad design. Better way would be to have some `friends` cross-table. Also use `mysqli` or `PDO` parametrized queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Yes buddy you are right. I am learning pdo but I am at initial stage. Actually I have purposely used symmetrical design because it made easier for me to show friends on both the sides

Comment: It is much easier to make `users` table with all the user data and `friends` table with coupled ids from `users` You can just use joins to search or users friends and friends of user friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you have a separate table for friendship notification? Meaning when user1 is friend with user2 you insert the details to the friendship notification table.

table structure

```
id   reqeust_sent_by   request_accepted_by  friendship_date
```

So let's assume John sends friend request and then Jack accepts the request, when Jack accepts the request then you insert that detail to the table. You better use mysqli prepared statements or pdo. So here is mysqli prepared statements

```
 $request_sender  = 'John';
 $logged_user = 'Jack';
 $date =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $mydabtase  = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database_name');
 $stmt = $mydatabse->prepare("insert into friendship_notification (request_sent_by, request_accepted_by, friendship_date) values (?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param('sss' $request_sender, $logged_user, $date);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
```

now to select the data you can do

```
 $stmt = $mydatabase->prepare("select * from friendship_notification where request_sent_by ! = ? or requst_accepted_by ! = ? order by id desc");//do your select here. here we are selecting where either rows are different from the logged in user because we don't want to show the logged in user that he has became friends with somebody else, we show this for other users.
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $logged_user, $logged_user);//follow the same procedure when binding the parameters, s means string. if you have 2 ? then you need 2 s along with 2 variables.
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();//this gets the results
 $total = $result->num_rows;//this returns the total number of rows for the above select query
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 //if the total is less than 3 people we do the below
 if($total < 3){
 echo $row['request_accepted_by']."is now friends with".$row['request_sent_by'].",";
 }
 elseif($total > 3 ){
   $stmt2 = $mydatabase->prepare("select * from friendship_notification where request_sent_by ! = ? or requst_accepted_by ! = ? order by id desc limit 1");//do your select here
 $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $logged_user, $logged_user);
 $stmt2->execute();
 $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
 $row2 = $result2->fetch_array();//we only need one row so no need for while loop.
   echo $row['request_accepted_by']."is now friends with".$row2['request_sent_by']."and ".$total-1." others.";
 }
 }
```

So this will display something like

`John is now friends with Max and magna.` and on the second case

`John is now friends with Max and 4 others.`

if you want the facebook way then you need to use ajax to auto refresh.

Comment: Hi magna. I have a seperate table for users notifications and the table structure is same as you suggested and also the data is inserted as the user accepts the friend request. And +1 for pdo code. Thank you so much. I am new to pdo so dont know how to write it for displaying complex queries

Comment: The query is going to be the same except you don't directly put variables like `where friend_1_username = $logged_user['username']` instead u do, `where friend_1_username = ?` then you bind the parameters like on the example. Okay so are you trying to do auto refresh like Facebook in this case?

Comment: Wow...just awesome...+1000 for your answer and support. Exactly the way I wanted it. Actually I have the auto refresh working but only this was a problem...muxh obliged

Comment: I'm glad I helped. you can play with the `$total` and then switch cases as you wish like `if $total < 2` or `if total > 2 ` and also you can adjust the select query the way you want it in order to show to the users you want. Good luck!!